# Set a default text value for a box in a Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I got the following Shiny Application:

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(textOutput("button_outcome")),
      box(width = 2,  actionButton("runRF", "Predict"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$runRF, {
    #output$button_outcome = DT::renderDataTable({
    # titanic_train <- select(titanic_train, Pclass, Name)
    # head(titanic_train,5)
    #})
    output$button_outcome = renderPrint({ "foo" })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This basically prints the text "foo" when I press a button. This all works. However, what I would like to have is a basic text that say something like "please press the button" and that when you press the button this is replaced by "foo"

So I am looking for a way to set a default value for button_outcome.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is bad practice to create a reactive or output from within an observer. See [this slide and the two after it from a presentation by Joe Cheng](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rstudio/reactivity-tutorial/master/slides.html#/exercise-0). In this case, we can store our text to display in a reaciveVal called `text_to_display`, which we can update from our observer, see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/reactiveVal.html) for details on ow they work. Example:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(textOutput("button_outcome")),
      box(width = 2,  actionButton("runRF", "Predict"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  text_to_display <- reactiveVal('Please press the button.')

  observeEvent(input$runRF, {
    text_to_display('foo') # set new value to reactiveVal
  })

  output$button_outcome = renderPrint({  text_to_display() })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can render the default text outside a reactive context

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$button_outcome <- renderPrint("please press the button")

  observeEvent(input$runRF, {
    output$button_outcome = renderPrint({ "foo" })
  })

}
```